# iMessage sticker pack extension doesn't load images

Tags: ios, imessage

i am in process of adding iMessage sticker pack extension in current AppStore application. I created new target from xcode and added imessage extension. I have added all the stickers to assets folder by adding stickerpack group. But it still not load any stickers when i open imessage. It does show my app there but not loading any images!

Comment: Follow this thread https://developer.apple.com/documentation/messages might be your images size is wrong or dimensions incorrect.

Comment: That's not the issue. Issue is adding imessage extension into existing iPhone app. If i build standalone iMessage app with that images then it works fine and if i add that stickers via extension into existing app then it's creating problem

Comment: you are doing something wrong , i am using extention app without any issue

Comment: can share your sample so i can check in my side

Comment: exact same issue, sticker extension from scratch project works, adding the same exact extension to existing app does not install the extension.... did you ever figure out the problem?